# CSS - Aligning div to edge of screen

Tags: css, html

I have a fixed width layout, it's very simple and looks like this:

[image]

The div on the left is position:fixed as I want it to remain in place as the page scrolls. The lines in the background represent a background image.

What I am trying to do is create a bar that runs from the side of the fixed div to the left hand side of the screen, so it would look like this:

[image]

Is there any way of achieving this? Normally I would use some kind of background image hack but I already have a background image behind the div so that just won't work.

Comment: please post the relevant code, preferably in a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com)

Comment: You might want to add a javascript tag if you would like to see solutions that include javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try this:

```
fixed-div:before {
    content: url(bar.gif);
}
```

There's an alternative, in case you want to put it on the right side *(after the element)*:

```
fixed-div:after {
    content: url(bar.gif);
}
```

Though, note that **IE6** and **IE7** doesn't support `:before` and `:after` pseudo-class selectors.